# How to optimize this oneliner? (if second column empty, put the line in another file)

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, performance

I have a little "oneliner":

```
while read ONELINE; do
  if [[ -n "`echo $ONELINE | awk '{print $2}'`" ]]; then
    echo "$ONELINE" >> LIST-ok.txt
  else
    echo "$ONELINE" >> LIST-notok.txt
  fi
done < ORIGINALLIST.txt
```

but it's extremely slow.. How can I optimize it to do the same thing but much-much faster? If the second column is empty then put the given line in another file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already tagged the question [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), so make use of it:

```
awk '{if (NF>=2) {print > "LIST-ok.txt"} else {print > "LIST-notok.txt"}}' filename
```

Another way of saying the same would be to make use of the ternary operator:

```
awk '{f=NF>=2?"LIST-ok.txt":"LIST-notok.txt"; print > f}' filename
```

Comment: @Gnouc Using `>>` instead of `>` would append to the files if the `awk` one-liner is executed multiple times.

Comment: wow. it's making several MBytes/second! can't say in words how big is the difference! wow.

Comment: neat one, the ternary operator

Answer (score 2):

The perl version of @devnull's awk oneliner:

```
perl -alne 'print { $#F ? stdout : stderr } $_' < original >list-ok 2>list-notok
```

Answer (score 1):

How about grep?

```
grep "[^ ][^ ]* [^ ]" <  ORIGINALLIST.txt > LIST-ok.txt
grep -v "[^ ][^ ]* [^ ]" <  ORIGINALLIST.txt > LIST-notok.txt
```